# DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument. Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get this

> DbLimitExpression requires a collection argument.

when I call the following code

```
ED.myEntities ctx = new ED.myEntities();
var res = ctx.User.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName.FirstOrDefault())
                    .Select(x => new{ K = x.Key,C= x.Count()}) 
                    .ToList();
```

What's the reason for this error and how can I prevent it?

I want to know how many Users exist with FirstName first letter "A", with "B" and so on..

Comment: Try `ctx.User.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName[0])` instead. Assuming `FirstName` is a string column, FirstOrDefault() is used for lists, ienumerables, etc only.

Comment: Try `ctx.User.GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.Left(x.FirstName, 1))`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov which namespace is `DbFunctions` ?

Comment: Are you sure the above is the code for searching the names with letters?

Comment: @GodofSource, System.Data.Entity

Comment: You can try with this: from c in ObjectName where c.FirstName[0] >= 'A' && c.FirstName[0] <= 'Z' select c;